# JQgrid with jquery UI autocomplete validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, autocomplete

What I have is jqgrid which uses jQueryUI autocomplete in a column. Everything works perfect except 1 little thing, if user choose to write "fsdfsdfsfasf" and press enter my program will of course freak out and tell me that such item does not exist.

What I want is to make some kind of validation, so if user enter some data which does not exist in autocomplete list program should automatically put autocomplete text to be `""` just like here: http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/ in the "month" field.

Since I am using jQueryUI autocomplete and not jquery autocomplete i cant use the `mustmatch` option.

```
{ 
    name: 'Brand', 
    index: 'Brand', 
    align: 'left', 
    width: 50, 
    sortable: true, 
    editable: true, 
    edittype: 'text', 
    editoptions: {
        dataInit:
        function (elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: '@Url.Action("GetBrands")',
                minChars: 0,
                max: 12,
                autoFill: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                matchContains: false,
                scrollHeight: 220,
                formatItem: function(data, i, total) {
                    return data[0];
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item.value == "Opret ny Brand...") {
                        $(function () {
                            var dialogDiv = $('#dialog');
                            var viewUrl = '@Url.Action("CreateBrand")';

                            $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
                                dialogDiv.html(data);

                                var $form = $("#updateCarForm");
                                $form.unbind();
                                $form.data("validator", null);

                                //Check document for changes
                                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

                                //Re add validation with changes
                                $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);

                                //open dialog
                                dialogDiv.dialog('open');
                            });

                        });
                    }
                }

            })
            .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a><span style='display:inline-block;width:60px;'><b>" +
                        item.value + "</b></span></a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
           };
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this functionality by providing a function as an argument to the `source` parameter of autocomplete and doing the AJAX request yourself. Something like:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        // Manually perform the AJAX request:
        var element = this.element;
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetBrands")', request, function (results) {
            // No results? Clear out the input field.
            if (!results.length) {
                element.val('');
            }
            // Notify the widget of the results.
            response(results);
        });
    }
});
```

*(Untested. You may need to tweak the AJAX call)*

I can provide a remote example if necessary, but the concept is the same with an example using a local data source: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Dgfgr/

Comment: it would be great with an example, since now i have 2 problems when i press down key full list is not shown anylonger, and i keep getting a JS error everytime i call an item which does not exsists in my list of brands

Comment: @Timsen: Just noticed that I had a line out of place. Can you check out my edit and let me know if that fixed any of the JS errors?

Comment: JS errors still comes in jquery 1.6.2 min.js file if i enter invalid data, but data shows up now on press down key

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'this.element' is null or not an object

Comment: @Timsen: Sorry, I've tried declaring a variable containing the element and then referencing it in the callback (I think the variable was out of scope inside the AJAX callback)

Comment: @Timsen: Awesome, sorry it took so long to get my act together `:)`